# String replace with pattern matching

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have the following variable string pulled from database and changes each time:

For example First time my string is:

> You can use the [xyz] Framework to develop [123], web, and [abc] apps

Second time my string is:

> You can use the [aaa] Framework to develop [bbb], web, and [ccc] apps

I would like to replace

- `[xyz]` or [aaa] with `.NET`,
- `[123]` or [bbb] with `desktop`, and
- `[abc]` or [ccc]  with `mobile`.

The text in the braces will change since it is a variable string but I want to replace the the text in first brace with `.NET`, text in second brace with `desktop` and text in third brace with `mobile`.

The transformed string should be -

> You can use the .NET Framework to develop desktop, web, and mobile apps:

What is the easiest way to do this using string replace in C#?

Comment: Do three separate replacements.  Three regexes like `s/the \[[^\]*\] Framework/the .Net Framework/` should work.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: If it is the same text everytime I can do three separate replacements but the text in the braces changes everytime.

Comment: Is the text actually in braces, or is that just for the example?  If there are no actual braces, then your regex would look more like `s/the\s+\S+\s+Framework/the .Net Framework/`...

Comment: Is it the `[xyz]` part that changes every time, or the `.NET` part, or both?

Comment: @abiessu: It is just an example! It changes each time. So we have to do pattern matching to replace the text in braces with the required strings.

Comment: Okay, I get that, but the question stands: can you give us an actual example string to work with?

Comment: @JLRishe: Just the text in braces changes each time not the .NET text.

Comment: @JLRishe: I modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with regular expressions:

```
// Error checking needed.....
string input = "You can use the [xyz] Framework to develop [123], web, and [abc] apps";
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\[[^\]]+\])");
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(input);
input = input.Replace(matches[0].Value, ".NET").Replace(matches[1].Value, "desktop").Replace(matches[2].Value, "mobile");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
var firstString = ".Net";
var secondString = "desktop";
var thirdString = "mobile";
var originalString = "You can use the {0} Framework to develop {1}, web, and {2} apps";
var newString = string.format(originalString, firstString,secondString,thirdString);
```

Comment: I don't think this matches with the OP's requirements, given that `[xyz]` and the others "will change since it's a variable string..."

Comment: string.Format() was meant for the exact situation OP was suggesting.

Comment: But you're altering the original string. How would OP get `{0}`, `{1}` or `{2}` in there?

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks for your response! I cannot do(var firstString = ".Net";) that since I am not sure what text it will be in the braces.. I am pulling that string from the database and it changes constantly. so, I have to use some kind of pattern.

Comment: Ah - well then this probably wouldn't work unless you alter the strings in the database to follow the pattern above.

Comment: You COULD use regex to find "[...whatever]" and replace them with "{#}" but that seriously sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: Give me a sec. I'll get another answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
// established sometime earlier
string firstPlaceholder = "[xyz]";
string secondPlaceholder = "[123]";
string thirdPlaceholder = "[abc]";

// then when you need to do the replacement
string result = originalString.Replace(firstPlaceholder, ".NET")
                              .Replace(secondPlaceholder, "desktop")
                              .Replace(thirdPlaceholder, "mobile");
```

Comment: *The text in the braces will change*

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I figured the asker could figure the rest out from what I provided, but I have modified my answer to move the placeholders into variables.

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer seems to be a little bit late

```
string input = "You can use the [xyz] Framework to develop [123], web, and [abc] apps";
var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"xyz",".NET"},
    {"123","desktop"},
    {"abc","mobile"},
};

var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[(.+?)\]", m => pairs[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

`You can use the .NET Framework to develop desktop, web, and mobile apps`

Answer (score 0):

Combining mine and Jonny Mopp's answer:

```
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\[[^\]]+\])");

        string origString = "You can [xyz] blah blah [abc]";

        var coll = reg.Matches(origString);

        for(int i=0;i<coll.Count; i++)
        {
            origString = origString.Replace(coll[i].Value,"{"+i+"}");
        }

        var newString = string.Format(origString,".Net","desktop");
```

Comment: That would work, but it seems to me that it's doing too much work to replace twice...

Comment: I tried to make it so that it would replace any number of brackets in the string.